# Is there a functin in "Networkx" for getting a connected subgraph giving any number of nodes

Tags: graph, networkx

I have a graph that containing 100 nodes.
Now, I want to know is there any function can get a subgraph when I giving a number of nodes, and that subgraph returned should **connected**.
I have try to used `G.subgraph` function, it works when the nodes I gaven are connected in Graph, but while the nodes I gaven aren't connected, `G.subgraph` will return more than one component to me.
For example, I have a Graph like below:

[image]

Giving **[A,B,G,I]** nodes:
[image]

The function that I want should return a subgraph that containing **[A,B,G,E,I]**, rather than **[A,B,G]** and **[I]**

Bad English, I hope you can understand my expression.

**Thank you very much for helping me.**

**Thank you very much for helping me.**

**Thank you very much for helping me.**